# One UDL Connection String for multiple forms

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008

I have a UDL file which points to a Database on SQL Server 2008.I want only one connection string pointing to the UDL File via Multiple forms without using app.config.Can anyone help me with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use a helper method like below (in a common assembly) wherever you need a connection. The path to the .udl file could be stored in your app.config.

```
   public static string CreateConnectionString(string udlFileName)
   {
     var connStrBld = new OleDbConnectionStringBuilder();
     connStrBld.FileName = udlFileName;   
     return connStrBld.ToString();
   }
```

Comment: ciprian Please read my question.I don't want to use app.config.Is it possible without app.config?

Comment: Then try reading from registry, or using persisted data from some common application folder like `AssemblyInfo.ApplicationFolder`, or use `OpenFileDialog`. My point was method above should be flexible enough.